Which prepositions can be used to fill in the blank: "The smoking rate _____ women"?

The smoking rate ______ women is 20% in this city.

I think among works well here, but I wonder what other prepositions are also okay. Maybe for? Feel free to recommend any that you find good.

You could also use "of", but it's not as common as "among". I also note some ambiguity by having "in this city" at the end of the sentence rather than following the word "women".

the smoking rate for women is self-referential, the study referring to itself, to its category "women" and the data being presented for that category.  for there means "pertaining to" and its complement (in this sense of the preposition) is a data category, an analyzed subset.
the smoking rate among women refers to women in the real-world and their smoking behavior.  The complement of among is a real-world group.

What is the politician's favorability rating among college-educated Latinos?
On what page do you show the politician's favorability rating for college-educated Latinos?

It's not that you couldn't ask the second question this way:

On what page do you show the politician's favorability rating among college-educated Latinos?

it's that you can't really ask the first question this way:

What is the politician's favorability rating for college-educated Latinos? unidiomatic

but you can ask it so:

Where is the politician's favorability rating for college-educated Latinos?

and there Where means in which section of this study, or on what page in this study, is that data presented?

So I take this answer as a yes for both prepositions. What do you think about @Astralbee's answer? While some don't, would some others consider for is not so good? I still remember your advice for me about not using a phrase which a group of people might consider incorrect if I want to play it safe.

@anIELTSlearner "A yes for both prepositions' is a very crude summary of my answer that ignores the core distinction the answer makes between the two prepositions and when you should use the one or the other. As far as Astralbee's answer is concerned, I believe we agree on what among means ("exists within that demographic") though I'm not sure what Astralbee meant by "assigned to".

I think I misunderstood your answer a little bit at first, and even after trying to grasp it, it's still pretty confusing. One of the reasons is your language used here might be rather advanced to me. I think it would help a lot if you could give a little more explanation for some examples, like what they mean and why I can't ask the fourth question that way. For me, I completely understand the examples using among, but the ones using for are kinda challenging.

The distinction is between the real-world behavior on the one hand, and the presentation of analytical data related to that behavior in a document, on the other.  When the references are to people, use among (e.g. "among women under 40").  But when you refer to an analytical category as presented in the document, you can use for. For example, "What's the smoking rate for category 'women age 18-39' ?" But that's a nuance you can avoid. You can always use "among". I just wanted to explain why you might sometimes encounter for. It is referring to something in the document itself.

for expresses a correspondence:  What is the number for category 'women aged 18-39' as shown on the chart?

'Among' is better than 'for', because the smoking rate is something that exists within that demographic rather than something that is being assigned to them, which the preposition 'for' could imply.

The reason why I thought of for is that "the figure" often goes with "for", I think even in situations where nothing is assigned to something else. For example: "The figure for China is 20 million (people)". I kinda linked "rate" with "figure" because a rate is also a figure, so that's why I thought "the rate for" might also work.

@anIELTSlearner But 'women' is a group noun referring to a set of female individuals, whereas "China" is a proper noun, the name of a country. It's not the country that is smoking, it's the people in it, so you're fine to assign the stat to the country with a preposition like "for". But, you would say "among the Chinese", because that's the people.
